# How to compute the reciprocal of big O

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Now I have the function

$$f(k) = \frac{k}{M + k + O(\frac{1}{k-1})}, k\in\{2, 3, \cdots\}, $$
where $M>1$ is a constant.
So how to get the big O form of $f(k)$? I mean can I get the following result
$$f(k) = \frac{1}{O(\frac{1}{k}) + 1 + O(\frac{1}{k(k-1)}) } =  \frac{1}{O(\frac{1}{k}) + 1  } = 1 - \frac{O(\frac{1}{k})}{O(\frac{1}{k} ) + 1} > 1 - O(\frac{1}{k})$$

Is there any better lower bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the best way (in my opinion) to manipulate $O$-expressions in multiplication/division/logarithms is to convert the absolute error $g(x) + O(h(x))$ into a relative error $g(x) \big( 1 + O\big( h(x)/g(x) \big) \big)$.

For example, the general shape of your function is
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x) + O(h(x))} = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \frac1{1 + O( h(x)/g(x) )}.
$$
Now the Maclaurin expansion of $\frac1{1+u}$ at $u=0$ is $1-u+\cdots$, and therefore
$$
\frac1{1 + O( h(x)/g(x) )} = 1 - O\bigg( \frac{h(x)}{g(x)} \bigg)
$$
assuming that $h(x)/g(x)\to0$ (or somewhat weaker). [Of course, unless we know the sign of $h(x)/g(x)$, there's no difference between the notations $1 - O(h(x)/g(x))$ and $1 + O(h(x)/g(x))$.] This is also the best we can get if the $O(h(x))$ term really is of size $h(x)$, because the fraction $1/\big( 1+h(x)/g(x) \big)$ really is asymptotically of size $1 - h(x)/g(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helps a lot. I have another similar problem in the form $\frac{xM + xy + O(\frac{1}{y-1})}{yM + xy + O(\frac{1}{x-1})}$. Could you give me any idea how to deal with this function?

Comment: Convert both numerator and denominator to relative error, move the denominator error into the numerator using the method in this answer, and then multiply the two relative errors together using $(1+O(a))(1+O(b)) = 1+O(max{a,b})$ (assuming both $a$ and $b$ are small).